# Incorrect encoding with Cyrillic in PHP contact form

Tags: php, forms, character-encoding, contacts

I'm new to using PHP and forms so if someone is willing to help, I'll be extremely grateful.

I have a contact form, but it doesn't send any Cyrillic characters correctly. I know that I have to put `Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` somewhere in the code but I have no idea where to put it exactly. The form element is set to post in `UTF-8`, but it doesn't seem to work correctly with the PHP file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$my_email = "myemailaddress@mail.com";
$from_email = "";
$continue = "index.php";
$errors = array();
// Remove $_COOKIE elements from $_REQUEST.
if (count($_COOKIE)) {
  foreach(array_keys($_COOKIE) as $value) {
    unset($_REQUEST[$value]);
  }
}
// Validate email field.
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['family']) && !empty($_REQUEST['about'])) {
  $_REQUEST['email'] = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
  if (substr_count($_REQUEST['email'], "@") != 1 || stristr($_REQUEST['email'], " ")) {
    $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
  } else {
    $exploded_email = explode("@", $_REQUEST['email']);
    if (empty($exploded_email[0]) || strlen($exploded_email[0]) > 64 || empty($exploded_email[1])) {
      $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
    } else {
      if (substr_count($exploded_email[1], ".") == 0) {
        $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
      } else {
        $exploded_domain = explode(".", $exploded_email[1]);
        if (in_array("", $exploded_domain)) {
          $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
        } else {
          foreach($exploded_domain as $value) {
            if (strlen($value) > 63 || !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i', $value)) {
              $errors[] = "Email address is invalid";
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
// Check referrer is from same site.
if (!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))) {
  $errors[] = "You must enable referrer logging to use the form";
}
// Check for a blank form.
function recursive_array_check_blank($element_value) {
  global $set;
  if (!is_array($element_value)) {
    if (!empty($element_value)) {
      $set = 1;
    }
  } else {
    foreach($element_value as $value) {
      if ($set) {
        break;
      }
      recursive_array_check_blank($value);
    }
  }
}
recursive_array_check_blank($_REQUEST);
if (!$set) {
  $errors[] = "You cannot send a blank form";
}
unset($set);
// Display any errors and exit if errors exist.
if (count($errors)) {
  foreach($errors as $value) {
    print "$value<br>";
  }
  exit;
}
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) {
  define("PHP_EOL", strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == "WIN") ? "\r\n" : "\n");
}
// Build message.
function build_message($request_input) {
  if (!isset($message_output)) {
    $message_output = "";
  }
  if (!is_array($request_input)) {
    $message_output = $request_input;
  } else {
    foreach($request_input as $key = > $value) {
      if (!empty($value)) {
        if (!is_numeric($key)) {
          $message_output. = str_replace("_", " ", ucfirst($key)).
          ": ".build_message($value).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
        } else {
          $message_output. = build_message($value).
          ", ";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return rtrim($message_output, ", ");
}
$message = build_message($_REQUEST);
$message = $message.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.
"-- ".PHP_EOL.
"Thank you for using the contact form.";
$message = stripslashes($message);
$subject = $_REQUEST['about'];
$subject = stripslashes($subject);
if ($from_email) {
  $headers = "From: ".$from_email;
  $headers. = PHP_EOL;
  $headers. = "Reply-To: ".$_REQUEST['email'];
} else {
  $from_name = "";
  if (isset($_REQUEST['name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['name'])) {
    $from_name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);
  }
  $headers = "From: {$from_name} <{$_REQUEST['email']}>";
}
mail($my_email, $subject, $message, $headers); ?> 



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your mail has been sent!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset = utf - 8 ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <center>
        <b>Thank you <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['name'])){print stripslashes($_REQUEST['name']);} ?></b>
        <br>Your mail has been sent!
        <p><a href="<?php print $continue;?>">Click here to continue</a></p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добави това:

```
    $headers = "From: " . $from_email;
    $headers .= PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_REQUEST['email'];
    //новия код (new code)
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n" ."Content-type: text/plain; charset='utf-8'". "\r\n";
```

Няма да е лошо да сложиш и някаква форма на верификация (картинка с код примерно, който трябва да се въведе, т.нар. CAPTCHA code) преди пращане от юзера, иначе всеки спам бот ще ти ползва формата за пращане на мейли, порови тук има доста начини за справяне с проблема.

Translated: (It is not bad idea to put some sort of verification code, an image with code inside of it, a so called CAPTCHA before sending the email, because otherwise every spam bot from Internet will use your form for mailing, check here for more ways to deal with the problem.)

Comment: I corrected myself before your post (also I don't know where my comment went, either :/). http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site, so we do need questions and answers to be in English. Could you at least provide a side-by-side English translation of your answer?

Comment: Don't use `PHP_EOL` to separate headers. Mail headers must be separated by the full `"\r\n"`, while on some systems, `PHP_EOL` is just `"\r"`. (On other systems, `PHP_EOL` is `"\r\n"`. It varies.)